# android ddms screen capture vertical size seems fixed at 1024

Tags: android, ddms

I can successfully run the DDMS screen capture either via the DDMS.bat file or via eclipse however the screen size in the vertical direction seems fixed at about 1024 pixels. 
My laptop is a bit small with a screen size of 1366x768.  If I attach a VGA monitor running at 1280x1024 then this portrait view just barely fits. I can rotate the view and display within my 1366 landscape view but was hoping there was a way to change the view size.

The problem is that I need to make a demo of this with my laptop connected to a projector.  The projector will be behind me thus I prefer to duplicate my (smaller) main screen (the 1366x768) onto the projector.

Comment: you can capture the screen shot then use the saved image for projecting or other..There would not be any resolution problem

Answer (score 1):

From within Eclipse:

```
1.Go to Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager -> Virtual Devices
2.Select the AVD you want to launch and click Start
3.Check the "Scale display to real size" button
4.Enter how big you want it to appear in inches and press Launch.
```

usually, 8 works great